# ASP.net Printing via process - Catch Exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am creating PDF's and then sending them to print, the problem I have is that I cant seem to catch an exception. My code as is follows:

```
Try
  Dim Process1 As New Process
  Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe", "/t " + filenamehere+ " printerhere")
  psi.UseShellExecute = False
  Process1.StartInfo = psi
  Process1.Start()
  Process1.WaitForInputIdle()
  Process1.CloseMainWindow()

Catch ex As Exception

  sendStatus = PrintStatus.ErrorPrinting
End Try
```

So I am trying to find out if the file does print/ if the printer is reached or however you would like to put it.

Does anyone know if this is possible from this way of printing? If not does anyone know a way to be able to print and catch an error if the file was NOT printed.

Comment: Erm, printing in asp.net can be done only the way you want to print using a machine that is accessible to the server, where do you have your website (either a local machine or local network). Is this what you want? Because you can't print with C#/VB.NET (=server-side code) on a clients machine over the internet.

Comment: @walther This is via a local network. I have it connected to the printer just fine and it will print. I just need to find a way to get a error if say the printer was no longer connected. So it would be trying to print to a printer that no longer exists. I need an error saying "Printing Error". If that makes sense.

Comment: If it's a network printer, you should be able to reach it via IP for instance, trying to send a ping and see if the printer still listens. Not sure if you can determine actually fact whether if the document has been printed or not, because.. Well, let's be honest, even Windows struggles with it so often :)

Comment: @walther Yeah I had the idea to ping it before hand and it is a way that can be done (not the best for me). I just want to see if it is possible to get something back from adobe reader or some other way (e.g. false or true) to confirm it has printed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following

```
    Dim PSI As New ProcessStartInfo
    PSI.FileName = filenamehere
    PSI.Verb = "print"
    PSI.Arguments = ""
    PSI.UseShellExecute = True
    PSI.CreateNoWindow = False

    Using Report As Process = New Process
        Report.StartInfo = PSI
        Report.Start()
        Report.WaitForExit()

        ' Check Report.ExitCode here

    End Using
```

Please keep in mind that this code was written on the fly, and thus is un-tested